# Undefined Control Sequence \hyper@link error

Tags: beamer, errors

Every time I compile my beamer presentation, I get a list of 83 errors all of the form:

```
Undefined Control Sequence
\hyper@link...d@pdflink {#1}{#2}#3\Hy@xspace@end
\close@pdflink
```

at each `\end{frame}` line.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal example code](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the undesired bahaviour?

Comment: This sounds like a 'passing' issue with particular versions of `hyperref` Could you add `\listfiles` to a minimal example and add the resulting file list to your question?

Comment: You must update hyperref to version  v6.82f. or later. (The bug is in 6.82e). If there is no update available yet, you can try to add `\makeatletter\def\Hy@xspace@end{}\makeatother` after loading beamer as a temporarly workaround.

Comment: @Ulrike: You might want to post this as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

You must update hyperref to version v6.82f. or later. (The bug is in 6.82e). If there is no update available yet, you can try to add `\makeatletter\def\Hy@xspace@end{}\makeatother` after loading beamer as a temporarly workaround.

Comment: also see the original discussion: https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/dae78f3fedfe1867